# create a vector with corresponding value

Tags: r, vector

First of all, I had to create a vector with three objects.
So, I did:

```
three.objects <- c('pen', 'pencil', 'notebook')
```

Then, I had to create a vector with cost of three objects that correspond to three objects.

```
cost <- c('pen' <- 5, 'pencil' <- 10, 'notebook' <- 5)
```

Is the second one correct way to create a vector with values in it?

Comment: depends if you want the names or not; compare your result with `cost <- c('pen' = 5, 'pencil' = 10, 'notebook' = 5)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setNames` to create a `name`d` vector

```
cost <- setNames(c(5, 10, 5), three.objects)
cost
#     pen   pencil notebook 
#       5       10        5
```